# How do I create an anchor in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do I translate the following to a link_to tag?

```
Click <a href="#portfolio">here</a> to see my portfolio.
....
<a name="portfolio"></a>
```

Comment: Just a small tip: `<a name="portfolio"></a>` is not necessary anymore. You can just use the `id` of an element for that. E.g. if you have `<div id="portfolio">...</div>` a link to `#portfolio` will jump to that div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first link, it's appropriate to use the Rails `link_to` method. If you pass in a string beginning with a hash as the second parameter, it will be assigned to the `href` attribute.

For your second link, the only way to generate an `<a>` tag **without** the `href` attribute in Rails is to use [`content_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper.html#method-i-content_tag). Using `link_to` will necessarily add the `href` attribute – *even* if you pass in a blank string.

```
Click <%= link_to 'here', '#portfolio' %> to see my portfolio.
...
<%= content_tag('a', '', :name => 'portfolio') %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Click `<%= link_to "here", '#portfolio' %>` to see my portfolio.

Answer (score 0):

You can code it like this:

```
<%= link_to "#portfolio" do %>
  Click here to to see my portfolio.
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<%= link_to "here", :anchor => 'portfolio' %>`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

**your link**

```
<%= link_to 'here', '#portfolio' %>
```

**will anchor here**

```
content_tag(:a, 'here', :name => 'portfolio')
```