# In Rails apply anchor tags depending on url

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using a CMS that templated a bunch of websites and I need to apply skip navigation to these pages.

So in the default template that they are drawing on I have the following:

```
<a href="#some-content">Skip to Some Content</a>
<a href="#other-content">Skip to Other Content</a>
<a href="#yes-content">Skip to Yes Content</a>
```

Then in the CMS I applied the id to the content

```
<div id="some-content">Stuff</div>
```

What I'm trying to do is only apply the anchor tags when it's actually on that page.

So if for example I'm on the Other Content page it's not displaying all the anchor tags.

My thought was the following helper:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def current_url(url)
   url = request.path_info
   if url.include?('other')
     content_tag :a, href: '#other-content'
   end
  end
end
```

Then I replaced the anchor tags with

```
<%= current_url %>
```

And...ActionView::Template::Error (wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1))

Is there something wrong with my helper?

I've also tried the following with the same result in my helper:

```
def original_url
 base_url + original_fullpath
end

def anchor_update
  if original_url.include?('services')
    content_tag :a, href: '#services'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

> ActionView::Template::Error (wrong number of arguments (given 0,
>   expected 1))

Well, `current_url(url)` expects **one argument** and you are calling it as `<%= current_url %>` **without any argument** which lead to that error. From the looks of it, you should define the method without any argument as you are assigning the `url` **explicitly**.

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def current_url
   url = request.path_info
   if url.include?('other')
     content_tag :a, href: '#other-content'
   end
  end
end
```

Comment: Only issue here is the content_tag displays as <a>{:href=&gt;&quot;#services&quot;}</a> but...it works.

Comment: @Jake `content_tag` doesn't generate `href` attribute for `<a>` tag. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17086595/how-do-i-create-an-anchor-in-rails You need to change it to `link_to`

Comment: I got it to work using the content_tag(:a, 'Something Here', :href => '#other-content')

Answer (score 0):

You are missing param in `<%= current_url %>` it should look as `<%= current_url(url) %>`